# Remove single class from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a element with multiple classes, however I want to remove just one when the removeClass method is called. Looking through the documentation I tried the following:

Element

```
  <div class="item active"></div>
```

Code

```
    active = $(".active");
    active.removeClass(function () {
        return $(this).attr("active");
    });
```

I just want the active class to be removed, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: `removeClass` will remove a single class... or you want to remove the class only from the first element that has it?

Comment: What class are you trying to remove? It works like this: `.removeClass('classToBeRemoved');`

Comment: Why would you guys down vote my question. If you read it correctly you would realize that I want to remove just the active but not the item class or reference .

Comment: I imagine because that statement makes little to no sense.

Comment: @MarioDennis if your issue has been solved by an answer below please accept it. Otherwise, Submit your solution, with details and attribution, below and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The `removeClass` function takes a string for this purpose

```
active.removeClass('active');
```

It also accepts a function, but for another purpose, you can read about it here: http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: That removes both item and active class. I just want to remove the active class

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
active.attr('class','item');
```